# Do we need separate tags for (betting) and (gambling)?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Quite recently the [betting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) has been created. However, for a long time there is a tag called [gambling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambling). To me the two tags seem rather similar

Personally, I do not see great need for a new tag. And a [quick search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgambling%5D+bet) suggests that this tag has been used in the past for questions about betting.

What would be the most reasonable way to handle these two tags?

- Keep them separate?
- Make them synonyms? (And if yes, what should be the master tag.)
- Completely removing one of the tags and leaving only the other one?
- Some completely different course of action?

You can find [here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34785154#34785154) a brief exchange of comments with the tag creator.

Comment: Merge them. I wasn't aware of the "gambling" tag.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You mean merge without making them synonyms (which would remove the new tag) or synonymizing them and then merge?

Comment: I am fine with both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just created a [betting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) → [gambling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambling) synonym, and merged the former into the latter.

I'm not exactly sold on the *usefulness* of either tag, but for the time being I guess they are basically talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 27):

In the question I have mentioned several possible actions. To me the most reasonable seem to be creating a synonym [betting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) $\to$ [gambling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambling). (I.e., with (gambling) as the master tag.)

In this way when somebody asks a new question and wants to add a tag, if they start typing "betting" in the tag field, they will be shown the synonym.

I am posting this as an answer, so that other users can vote and comment on this particular suggestion.

Comment: Pretty straightforward, obvious solution.  The English word "gamble" means specifically betting on the outcome of a game of chance, whereas a "bet" could be about anything (politics, tomorrow's weather, whatever), but in the context of a mathematical Q&A site I can't imagine any *on topic* question about "betting" that couldn't be tagged with "gambling."  Go for it.